# nested forms with pre populated data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, simple-form

I am having an issue managing a has_many :through association via nested form

when creating a product i want to display all tags from tags table
and create a new record in product_tags table with some extra information

is this possible  thanks for help

Models

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :product_tags

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_tags, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end

class ProductTag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :tag
end

class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_tags
  has_many :products, through: :product_tags
end

View
= simple_form_for @product do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :price
  = f.fields_for :tags do |tag|
    b tag.object.name
    = tag.fields_for :product_tags do |product_tag|
      = product_tag.input :tag_id, as: :hidden, input_html{value:tag.object.id}
      = product_tag.input :priority
      = product_tag.input :status
```

Comment: only 1 tag shows up on the page i have 4 tags in the table

Comment: Did not get your issue ? you want prepopulate the data? add   `:value` in fields .

Comment: i want to pre populate all the tags with there names and then show fields for product_tag table

Comment: Your tags model is missing accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_tags